# 'Code First From Database' Template not showing in Visual Studio Entity Data Model Wizard

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-6

according to Microsft in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx) is should see an option 'Code First From Database'
when adding a new item to the project under 'ADO.NET Entity Data Model' in step 3.

I see the following only [image]

I have installed EF 6.1 using nuget, I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate..What am i missing?

Comment: You should really accept your answer as it is the solution and appears at the bottom for the both the active and oldest tabs. This is one of those cases where a "Flag for for moderator answer acceptance would be good" or even something to where with enough votes the answer could be accepted by the community.

Comment: done. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It turns out that to enable the "Code First From Database" template, you need to [download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762) and install the EF Tools.

Comment: I had to do this for VS2013 as well. I was following a EF tutorial from Microsoft and the doc said VS2013 ships with this tool. Not in my case...

Comment: Still not working for me in VS2013 after doing this :/

Comment: I was following same Microsoft example as the OP.  This works for me in VS2013 Professional (Update 3) - downloading the VS2013 version of tools in @kurasa's link.  I added nuget reference to 6.1.2 version of Entity Framework initially which didn't show the wizard templates.  About to put Update 4 on though next.

Comment: Thanks @kurasa very much

Answer (score 11):

1. Install "Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4" (Tools -> Extensions and Updates)
2. Right click project, select "Entity Framework", and "Reverse Engineer Code First"

Answer (score 1):

Probably my response is too late! but for others "internautas" probably it works!... In my case the problem was the .NET Framework version, if you create an application and you use a .NET framework is less or equal 3.5 you don't see the option, but if you use 4 or 4.5 the option is visible

Cheers from El Salvador, Central America.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

*Solution:* Download EF6.1.3 updated version from [MS download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762)

[image]

**In detail**

I found all of the previous answers leading towards a solutions, but desipe others claiming to have successfully fixed and issue - I wasn't feeling the same.

But reinstalling eftools.msi got me thinking - why would I reinstall what's already installed when I know that I'm still missing "code first" option.
and so I got myself fresh install from [microsoft downloads page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762) which for today offers 6.1.3 version.

Success! And it's time to return to [EntityFramework tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/dbcontext-vs-objectcontext.aspx) :)

Answer (score -1):

You should check out this [EntityFramework Reverse POCO Code First Generator](https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator) project which consists of  **T4 templates to do Code First from an Existing Database**.

Those templates are very easy to use, fully customizable, and are much more complete than the original EF wizard.

Strongly recommend it.

Answer (score -3):

Try to Update the Visual studio or to download EF tools.

Comment: It is already mentioned that Visual Studio 2012 is being used.